# Is there any difference within the port Numbers that we use in Socket Programming?

Tags: sockets, tcp, network-programming, udp, port

I am still a beginner in Socket Programming, and I have come across several TCP/UDP Protocol based codes in which different portNumbers are used, but they all seem so random, also, I have set up client and server on my Virtual Machine, and every code works fine.

The port numbers used are 8080, 22000, 45434, etc.

I got a meaningful explanation for port 8080 but all others are so random, and I cannot seem to find their purpose on Google.

Comment: For example see on https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers

Comment: There are a number of standardized ports, such as SMTP=25, SSH=22, HTTP=80. They're arbitrary assignments.

Comment: See the IANA _[Service Name and Transport Protocol Port Number Registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml)_.

Comment: Why [tag:unix-socket]? Unix sockets don't have port numbers.

Comment: @user207421 Because I have been writing Socket Programming codes on Linux, that's why I added the 'UNIX-Socket' tag. Did I make a mistake?

Comment: @ulix I referred the list you mentioned. But what abou those port numbers that aren't there under Well known ports or Reserved ports? Like in the examples I mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are essentially random, with no inherent meaning. The TCP protocol doesn't care which ports you use.

There are a few conventions:

- Valid port numbers are from 1 to 65535.
- Ports 49152-65535 are chosen (randomly) by your operating system when you make an outgoing connection and don't choose a port yourself. Both ends of a connection have a port number, but usually we only care about the server's port number, and the client OS chooses a random one.
- On Linux-like operating systems, only the admin user ("`root`") can bind to ports 1-1023. Windows has no such restriction.

Most kinds of servers have "default" ports that the client will use by default. HTTP is 80, HTTPS is 443, SMTP is 25, Minecraft is 25565, Counter-Strike is 27015. You can usually use a different port *but* then the client has to be told what the port is. If you want to go to Stack Overflow on port 443 you can type in https://stackoverflow.com/ but if you want port 444 you have to type https://stackoverflow.com:444/ - it doesn't work, of course, because they do use port 443.

Important Internet services like HTTP are registered with the Internet Assigned Numbers Authority. Non-important services like games usually just pick them at random between 1024 and 49151. If you want to run two games on the same server and they both use the same port, you have to change one, but that doesn't happen very often. People tend to want memorable ones, so if you want to run two web servers, then 8080 and 8000 and 81 are popular. 1234 and 12345 are popular choices for toy programs. It doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score -1):

Ports 1025 and above are basically open for use by any user-space programs, but there are conventions here. On POSIX-type systems you'll usually have something like `/etc/services` which outlines what the intent is for any given port number.

When assigning your own port to a service you're creating, you can pick as you see fit, but the best practice is to avoid a known service to prevent any confusion.

Ports 1-1024 are often restricted to processes with specific access, where the intention here was to prevent regular users from spinning up things like fake SSH or HTTP servers. While you can pick a lower port number, keep in mind this may inconvenience users looking to use your program.

Comment: "_Ports 1025 and above are basically open for use by any user-space programs, but there are conventions here._ No, the _[Service Name and Transport Protocol Port Number Registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml)_ explains about the three port number ranges. Also, "_User Ports (1024-49151) are assigned by IANA using the "IETF Review" process, the "IESG Approval" process, or the "Expert Review" process, as per 
[RFC6335]._" Only the Dynamic and/or Private Ports (49152-65535) are not assigned.

Comment: @RonMaupin In other words, there are conventions.

Comment: @RonMaupin *In reality*, people ignore the IANA, and choose randomly from this range.

Comment: Yes, and when there is a collision with an existing application, the offending application gets rejected by companies that properly test such things. We have rejected applications because the vendor did not register its own ports and used ports registered by another company. Most of them falsely claim they are open for anyone to use, but why trust a network application from a company that really does not understand such a simple concept. That is a fast way to introduce vulnerabilities into your company network.